# How can I make the following python program(code) more efficient?

Tags: python, performance, list, dictionary

Any efficient way to solve the following problem assuming data is large. I solved the problem but how can I improve the code, which will make it efficient. any suggestions?

Data:

```
movie_sub_themes = {
'Epic': ['Ben Hur', 'Gone With the Wind', 'Lawrence of Arabia'],
'Spy': ['James Bond', 'Salt', 'Mission: Impossible'],
'Superhero': ['The Dark Knight Trilogy', 'Hancock, Superman'],
'Gangster': ['Gangs of New York', 'City of God', 'Reservoir Dogs'],
'Fairy Tale': ['Maleficent', 'Into the Woods', 'Jack the Giant Killer'],
'Romantic':['Casablanca', 'The English Patient', 'A Walk to Remember'],
'Epic Fantasy': ['Lord of the Rings', 'Chronicles of Narnia', 'Beowulf']}

movie_themes = {
'Action': ['Epic', 'Spy', 'Superhero'],
'Crime' : ['Gangster'],
'Fantasy' : ['Fairy Tale', 'Epic Fantasy'],
'Romance' : ['Romantic']}

themes_keys = movie_themes.keys()
theme_movies_keys = movie_sub_themes.keys()

#Iterate in movie_themes
#Check movie_themes keys in movie_sub_keys
#if yes append the movie_sub_keys into the newdict
newdict = {}
for i in range(len(themes_keys)):
   a = []
   for j in range(len(movie_themes[themes_keys[i]])):
     try:
         if movie_themes[themes_keys[i]][j] in theme_movies_keys:
            a.append(movie_sub_themes[movie_themes[themes_keys[i]][j]])
     except:
         pass
   newdict[themes_keys[i]] = a

# newdict contains nested lists
# Program to unpack the nested list into single list
# Storing the value into theme_movies_data 
theme_movies_data = {}
for k, v in newdict.iteritems():
    mylist_n = [j for i in v for j in i]
    theme_movies_data[k] = dict.fromkeys(mylist_n).keys()

print (theme_movies_data)
```

Output:

```
{'Action': ['Gone With the Wind', 'Ben Hur','Hancock, Superman','Mission: Impossible','James Bond','Lawrence of Arabia','Salt','The Dark Knight Trilogy'],
 'Crime': ['City of God', 'Reservoir Dogs', 'Gangs of New York'],
 'Fantasy': ['Jack the Giant Killer','Beowulf','Into the Woods','Maleficent','Lord of the Rings','Chronicles of Narnia'],
 'Romance': ['The English Patient', 'A Walk to Remember', 'Casablanca']}
```

Apologies for not properly commenting the code.

I am more concern about the running time.

Thank you..

Comment: try https://codereview.stackexchange.com for help with working code.

Comment: To make your code work at Python 3 - pass the two keys() (now View Objects) to the list function, and replace .iteritems() with just .items().

Answer (score 0):

You could use a relational database to store two tables, one of movies and their sub-theme and one relating sub-themes to movie themes. You could then use SQL to query the database, selecting a list of all movies and their associated movie themes.

This approach would be more efficient, as SQL commands tend to be compiled for speed of processing. The relational database model is very scalable, and so will work for very large datasets with minimal overhead.

For an example of creating and using a simple database in Python, see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html). If you are not familiar with SQL operations, see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/) for a simple tutorial on the useful operations.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution (using defaultdict):

```
movie_sub_themes = {
'Epic': ['Ben Hur', 'Gone With the Wind', 'Lawrence of Arabia'],
'Spy': ['James Bond', 'Salt', 'Mission: Impossible'],
'Superhero': ['The Dark Knight Trilogy', 'Hancock, Superman'],
'Gangster': ['Gangs of New York', 'City of God', 'Reservoir Dogs'],
'Fairy Tale': ['Maleficent', 'Into the Woods', 'Jack the Giant Killer'],
'Romantic':['Casablanca', 'The English Patient', 'A Walk to Remember'],
'Epic Fantasy': ['Lord of the Rings', 'Chronicles of Narnia', 'Beowulf']}

movie_themes = {
'Action': ['Epic', 'Spy', 'Superhero'],
'Crime' : ['Gangster'],
'Fantasy' : ['Fairy Tale', 'Epic Fantasy'],
'Romance' : ['Romantic']}

from collections import defaultdict
newdict = defaultdict(list)

for theme, sub_themes_list in movie_themes.items():
    for sub_theme in sub_themes_list:
        newdict[theme] += movie_sub_themes.get(sub_theme, [])       

dict(newdict)

>> {'Action': ['Ben Hur',
  'Gone With the Wind',
  'Lawrence of Arabia',
  'James Bond',
  'Salt',
  'Mission: Impossible',
  'The Dark Knight Trilogy',
  'Hancock, Superman'],
 'Crime': ['Gangs of New York', 'City of God', 'Reservoir Dogs'],
 'Fantasy': ['Maleficent',
  'Into the Woods',
  'Jack the Giant Killer',
  'Lord of the Rings',
  'Chronicles of Narnia',
  'Beowulf'],
 'Romance': ['Casablanca', 'The English Patient', 'A Walk to Remember']}
```

timings: 4.84 µs vs 14.6 µs

Comment: Error on this line: newdict = defaultdict(list) -> TypeError: first argument must be callable or None...

Comment: Which version of python are you using - mine is 3.6.5.

Comment: I suspect you must have redefined the list function earlier.
Look for lines starting:
    list = ...

Comment: python version 2.7